# Hide/show rows by php+jQuery

Tags: slidetoggle

I'm very new in PHP and JS. I have table that form by PHP. I want to hide rows that formed by PHP.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"+"row-"+"<?php echo $line->id; ?>").click(function(){
        $("#"+"<?php echo $line->showOptionals($extrafields, 'view', array('style'=>'class="drag drop oddeven"', 'colspan'=>$coldisplay), '', '', 1); ?>").slideToggle("slow");
            });
    });
</script>
```

For each row that formed by $line->id, have each $line->showOptionals...

Is it possible? Because site crashed...

[Red row formed with $line->id, green rows formed with $line->showOptionals. If add more red row, list become very long. So i want to hide each green rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AppL0.png)

Server have ERR 500

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'view' (T_STRING) in htdocs/main.inc.php on line 1528, referer: /comm/index.php?mainmenu=commercial&leftmenu=

line 1528:

```
$("#"+"<?php echo print $line->showOptionals($extrafields, 'view', array('style'=>'class="drag drop oddeven"', 'colspan'=>$coldisplay), '', '', 1); ?>").slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: A site won't "crash" based on the given code. Can you share more details about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have added pic...if i just use name for each rows...it works...but if rows ID forms by PHP...stop working. I'm trying to modify Dolibarr ERP.

Comment: Please explain your problem further. I don't get what "crashed" means, is there any error message you could share?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Usually, there's something written to your server's error log when such an error occurs - please locate that log and attach the error message to your question

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - as far as that error message tells it, there's a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...my fault. The code was open by PHP, so one line was open by ' and close on '...i missed it. Thank you.